# Modified Poisson-Boltzmann confusion about chemical potential and electrostatic potential

Tags: density-functional-theory, implicit-solvent

Within the Poisson-Boltzmann formalism the boundary conditions are often chosen such as $\phi^{S}$, the electrostatic potential in bulk solution far away from the interface (Galvani potential) is equal to 0. Additionally because the nature of the interaction are only electrostatic in the solution we have $\mu_{e}^{S} = 0$ as well.

So if we want to compute the absolute potential in this framework we have:

$$E_{abs}^{mPB} = \mu_{e}^{S} - \mu_{e}^{M} - (\phi^{S} - \phi^{M}) = - \mu_{e}^{M} + \phi^{M} = -\tilde{\mu_{e}}^{M}$$

(https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5047829 II.E)

First of all, I am confused because for me the inner potential of the electrode ($\phi^{M}$) was always equal to the Fermi energy (with a sign) = $-\mu_{e}^{M}$ which doesn't make sense here, could someone clarify?

EDIT: It's been a while since I asked this question and I can now add some more details. The fermi Energy is $-\tilde{\mu_{e}}^{M}$ the electrochemical potential and not $- \mu_{e}^{M}$ if we trust the same paper. My question now is, how do we obtain $\phi_{M}$ from a DFT calculation?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but have you got an answer from elsewhere over the last few months? Are you still actively in need of an answer to this particular question? Please update us!

Comment: @NikeDattani Actually I should be able to rephrase the question now.

Comment: It looks like you have answered your first question in your most recent edit and are now asking a second question. Why not write a self-answer to the first question and ask the second question separately? This will make everything more clear. Im this fast-paced world, people are unlikely to make it to your last sentence, where the important question for you is located.